# Why are sqlite databases located on sdcard readonly when using min-sdk tag in manifest?

Tags: android, android-manifest

I have posted this question over a week ago on the Android dev list but so far no responses.

I have run into a weird issue. I work with a database located on /sdcard/ and for some reason whenever I add `<uses-sdk android:minSdkVersion="8" />` to the manifest sqlite opens the db as read only. It gets a bit weirder too. The below code opens the db and checks if the db is readonly, which returns false:

`db = SQLiteDatabase.openDatabase("/sdcard/test.db3", null,
SQLiteDatabase.OPEN_READWRITE);
Log.i(LOGTAG, "Database status: " + db.isReadOnly());`

but if I try to write any data it bombs with:

`INFO/Database(6576): sqlite returned: error code = 8, msg = prepared
statement aborts at 24: [INSERT INTO tags(type_id , tag)
VALUES(?, ?);]
ERROR/Database(6576): Error inserting type_id =1 tag=TestTag
ERROR/Database(6576): android.database.sqlite.SQLiteException: error
code 8: attempt to write a readonly database`

If I remove the uses-sdk tag from manifest everything works fine. I verified this behavior on the emulator, NexusOne running 2.2.1 and Galaxy Tab. Is this a known issue? Is there a workaround?

Any help will be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You need the `WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE` permission.

Also, never never never never never hardcode the path to external storage the way you are doing. Your code will break on Android 2.2 devices. Your code will break on other devices. Use `Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory()`, please.

Comment: Thanks. That does it. I actually figured it out on my own a few seconds ago, but thanks for the prompt help.